# How to pass values of checkboxes from JavaScript/view to controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, view, controller

I am working on a form which enables a maximum of 11 football players to be selected from a list using checkboxes. They are separated and named based on their playing position.

```
@if(item.PlayerPosition.FantasyFootball_PlayerToSeason.Select(x => x.PositionID == 1).FirstOrDefault()) {
    @Html.CheckBox("goalkeepers", false)
}

@if(item.PlayerPosition.FantasyFootball_PlayerToSeason.Select(x => x.PositionID == 2).FirstOrDefault()) {
    @Html.CheckBox("defenders", false)
}

@if(item.PlayerPosition.FantasyFootball_PlayerToSeason.Select(x => x.PositionID == 3).FirstOrDefault()) {
    @Html.CheckBox("midfielders", false)
}

@if(item.PlayerPosition.FantasyFootball_PlayerToSeason.Select(x => x.PositionID == 4).FirstOrDefault()) {
    @Html.CheckBox("forwards", false)
}
```

I am using the following piece of JavaScript to display each of the selected values in order inside a pop-up box when a button is clicked.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(0).val()); // 1st
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(1).val()); // 2nd
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(2).val()); // 3rd
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(3).val()); // 4th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(4).val()); // 5th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(5).val()); // 6th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(6).val()); // 7th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(7).val()); // 8th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(8).val()); // 9th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(9).val()); // 10th
    alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(10).val()); // 11th
});
```

However, what I really want to do with these values is pass them through to the controller so that I can record them in the database. These checkboxes are placed within a partial view and are not part of this particular model which is why it's not so straightforward (at least as far as I can see).

Basically, everything is working as I would like apart from not being able to record the IDs of each player that has been selected. I am thinking that there must be a way of doing this - either by expanding on what I have done slightly or by using a different approach.

Ideally, I would like to record each of the eleven values separately rather than as an array.

Here is an extract from my controller where I would like to add the values to my table (currently commented out):

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FantasyTeamID,Id,FantasyTeamTypeID,Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5,Player6,Player7,Player8,Player9,Player10,Player11,FirstEntered,LastUpdated,FormationID,GameweekID")] FantasyFootball_FantasyTeam fantasyfootball_fantasyteam)
    {

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        db.FantasyFootball_FantasyTeam.Add(fantasyfootball_fantasyteam);
          fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
          fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.FantasyTeamTypeID = 1;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player1 = 2398;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player2 = 491;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player3 = 850;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player4 = 461;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player5 = 2845;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player6 = 482;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player7 = 1028;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player8 = 2516;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player9 = 2586;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player10 = 2230;
          //fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.Player11 = 2893;
          fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.FirstEntered = DateTime.Now;
          fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.FormationID = 1;
          fantasyfootball_fantasyteam.GameweekID = 47;
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will pass all checkboxes values in an array and pass save to the controller and apply the loop one by one and store the value in DB.

```
Array trans = new Array();
trans.push($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').eq(0).val());
```

Then pass same array trans to MVC action.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not quite sure how everything is supposed to fit together. What needs to go where? I have added some further code from my controller which may help you to explain in this regard. Thanks a lot.